# Building Gerrit from source using Bazel. Error at the verry first time. Are my expectetions too high?

Tags: bazel, gerrit

at my work we are using Gerrit v3.4.1. I wanted to have a closer look, so I said "let's compile Gerrit first from source". Oh, that needs Bazel, fine. For the first time, I downloaded it ([bazel-4.2.1-windows-x86_64.exe](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/4.2.1/bazel-4.2.1-windows-x86_64.exe)) and I cloned the Gerrit v3.4.1 also.

According to Gerrit's [README](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/v3.4.1), I must issue only the

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
cd gerrit && bazel build release
```

command. I did nothing more, it was the first time, that I tried to use bazel. And tada, errors:

```
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Invocation ID: a1bf852c-567c-4b77-8f67-dbd6a93dcae1
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=211
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  'build' options: --python_path=C:/Users/KI/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\users\KI\java\gerrit_source\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --workspace_status_command=python3 ./tools/workspace_status.py --repository_cache=~/.gerritcodereview/bazel-cache/repository --action_env=PATH --disk_cache=~/.gerritcodereview/bazel-cache/cas --java_toolchain=//tools:error_prone_warnings_toolchain_java11 --incompatible_strict_action_env --announce_rc --experimental_worker_multiplex=false
DEBUG: C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/bazel_toolchains/rules/rbe_repo/version_check.bzl:68:14:
Current running Bazel is ahead of bazel-toolchains repo. Please update your pin to bazel-toolchains repo in your WORKSPACE file.
DEBUG: C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/bazel_toolchains/rules/rbe_repo/checked_in.bzl:125:14: rbe_jdk11 not using checked in configs; Bazel version 4.2.1 was picked/selected but no checked in config was found in map {"0.20.0": ["8.0.0"], "0.21.0": ["8.0.0"], "0.22.0": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.0": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.1": ["8.0.0", "9.0.0"], "0.23.2": ["9.0.0"], "0.24.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.24.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.25.2": ["9.0.0"], "0.26.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.26.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.27.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.27.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.28.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.28.1": ["9.0.0"], "0.29.0": ["9.0.0"], "0.29.1": ["9.0.0", "10.0.0"], "1.0.0": ["9.0.0", "10.0.0"], "1.0.1": ["10.0.0"], "1.1.0": ["10.0.0"], "1.2.0": ["10.0.0"], "1.2.1": ["10.0.0"], "2.0.0": ["10.0.0"], "2.1.0": ["10.0.0"], "2.1.1": ["10.0.0", "11.0.0"], "2.2.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.0.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.1.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.2.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.3.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.3.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.4.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.5.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.5.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.6.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.0": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.1": ["11.0.0"], "3.7.2": ["11.0.0"], "4.0.0": ["11.0.0"]}
INFO: Repository npm instantiated at:
  C:/users/KI/java/gerrit_source/WORKSPACE:923:13: in <toplevel>
  C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/index.bzl:78:18: in yarn_install
Repository rule yarn_install defined at:
  C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl:650:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'npm':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 616, column 15, in _yarn_install_impl
                _copy_file(repository_ctx, repository_ctx.attr.package_json)
        File "C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 343, column 17, in _copy_file
                fail("mkdir -p %s failed: \nSTDOUT:\n%s\nSTDERR:\n%s" % (dirname, result.stdout, result.stderr))
Error in fail: mkdir -p _ failed:
STDOUT:

STDERR:
java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(202): CreateProcessW("mkdir" -p _): The system cannot find the file specified.
 (error: 2)
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 616, column 15, in _yarn_install_impl
                _copy_file(repository_ctx, repository_ctx.attr.package_json)
        File "C:/users/KI/_bazel_KI/sxhliick/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 343, column 17, in _copy_file
                fail("mkdir -p %s failed: \nSTDOUT:\n%s\nSTDERR:\n%s" % (dirname, result.stdout, result.stderr))
Error in fail: mkdir -p _ failed:
STDOUT:

STDERR:
java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(202): CreateProcessW("mkdir" -p _): The system cannot find the file specified.
 (error: 2)
ERROR: C:/users/KI/java/gerrit_source/BUILD:45:8: //:release depends on //plugins:core in repository @ which failed to fetch. no such package '@npm//@bazel/typescript': mkdir -p _ failed:
STDOUT:

STDERR:
java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(202): CreateProcessW("mkdir" -p _): The system cannot find the file specified.
 (error: 2)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:release' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 35.384s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (15 packages loaded, 5 targets configured)
    currently loading: plugins ... (2 packages)
```

Because I am using this version Gerrit (v3.4.1) I am convinced that it compiles without any error.  I downloaded the Bazel, I checked its hash and it was OK, I do think that it is the original file and it should work fine. At least I have this expectation.

But not. Why? Why is that? What did I do wrong? Or this is the normal Bazel behavior?

It would be nice to have something working out of box. Or my expectations are too high?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MSYS2. More details [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/install-windows.html#installing-compilers-and-language-runtimes)

It tries to call `mkdir` which is not present on your system:

```
STDERR:
java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(202): CreateProcessW("mkdir" -p _): The system cannot find the file specified.
 (error: 2)
```

Once MSYS2 is installed this should be fixed.